How can I remove a broken drawer pull screw?
While trying to remove the screw I used for a drawer pull, the handle’s “arm” broke off, leaving a very tight sort of glove (imagine a hollow screw fitting very tightly on another screw) on the screw itself, so there’s a normal screw head on one side of the drawer and another head like piece on the other side, making it impossible to pull out. I’ve tried pliers, wearing nylon gloves for more of a grip, and of course the drill, but nothing had worked to twist it off.


All this takes is proper use of a couple basic tools.

Grip the remaining shaft with a plier. A locking type (Vice-Grip) would work well, but any with a serrated jaw should work fine.

Remove the screw. Use a screwdriver or, if the head is boogered, another plier.


Alternatively, cut the head off the screw with a hack saw, rotary too and abrasive wheel, or a wire cutter. Pull out out the other way.
